# How to set margins as percentage of parent layout's size?

Tags: android, percentage, margins

I wanna set the margins as percentage.

like this..

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams margin = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(iv_Dot.getLayoutParams());
margin.setMargins(30%,  20%,  0,  0);
```

But, setMargins method is to support only int type.

How can i set margins as percentage?.

If, I get parent size.
and then, calculate percentage.
I can solve this problem.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than setting component sizes as percentage of parent, I do not think ther is another way.